# Prevent or forbid use of Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I wrote a library on top of `System.Data.SQLite` and realized it (my library) has unpredictable behaviour when using `Parallel.ForEach`. I might debug this eventually (i.e. if I get/take the time), most likely by locking the right parts, but for now let's say I want to just prevent usage of `Parallel.ForEach`, or force usage of my library to allow (or result in) only a single thread, how would I proceed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't control how your API is consumed by external code. If it's something you absolutely cannot address prior to release, it would be a good idea to be very explicit about failure cases in your documentation (both XML comments and any sort of "help file").

Comment: It just dawns on me that `Parallel.ForEach` (et al.) has revealed a *lot* of ticking time bombs. Access to unique resources, unchecked, unlocked...

Comment: Sounds like you have some refactoring to do!

Comment: "I felt a great disturbance in the Force, as if millions of threads suddenly cried out in terror and were suddenly silenced."

Comment: FYI, it turns out that I was adding to a `Dictionary`, when I should have used a `ConcurrentDictionary`. Not much refactoring beyond that.

Answer (score 3):

A few quick threadstatic attributes might solve your concurrency problem, but this smells like the tip of a much larger iceberg. Fix the root cause, not the symptom.